# R_how can I use str_sub to split date and time

Tags: r

The following file names were used in a camera trap study. The S number represents the site, P is the plot within a site, C is the camera number within the plot, the first string of numbers is the YearMonthDay and the second string of numbers is the HourMinuteSecond.

```
file.names <- c( 'S123.P2.C10_20120621_213422.jpg',
                 'S10.P1.C1_20120622_050148.jpg',
                 'S187.P2.C2_20120702_023501.jpg')
file.names
```

Use a combination of `str_sub()` and `str_split()` to produce a data frame with columns corresponding to the *site, plot, camera, year, month, days, hour, minute, and second* for these three file names. So we want to produce code that will create the data frame:

| Site | Plot | Camera | Year | Month | Day | Hour | Minute | Second |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S123 | P2 | C10 | 2012 | 06 | 21 | 21 | 34 | 22 |
| S10 | P1 | C1 | 2012 | 06 | 22 | 05 | 01 | 48 |
| S187 | P2 | C2 | 2012 | 07 | 02 | 02 | 35 | 01 |

My codes are below:

```
file.names %>%
  str_sub(start = 1, end = -5) %>%
  str_replace_all("_", ".") %>%
  str_split(pattern = fixed("."), n = 5)
```

I have no idea how to split date and time

Answer (score 2):

```
nms <- c("Site", "Plot", "Camera", "Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second")

library(tidyverse)
data.frame(file.names) %>%
  extract(file.names, nms, 
          '(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)_(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})_(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})')

  Site Plot Camera Year Month Day Hour Minute Second
1 S123   P2    C10 2012    06  21   21     34     22
2  S10   P1     C1 2012    06  22   05     01     48
3 S187   P2     C2 2012    07  02   02     35     01
```

in Base R:

```
type.convert(strcapture('(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)_(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})_(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})',
           file.names, as.list(setNames(character(length(nms)), nms))), as.is = TRUE)

 Site Plot Camera Year Month Day Hour Minute Second
1 S123   P2    C10 2012     6  21   21     34     22
2  S10   P1     C1 2012     6  22    5      1     48
3 S187   P2     C2 2012     7   2    2     35      1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a specific case where your data is pretty neatly formatted with fields separated by either `_` or `.`, and where the date and time fields have uniform character length. That means you can skip doing regex and instead just split by those delimeters, drop the substrings into a data frame, then separate the date components and the time components by their positions. As is often the case, as a tidyverse solution you're trading writing extra code for it being pretty easy to follow and scale.

```r
library(magrittr)

strsplit(file.names, split = "[._]") %>%
  purrr::map_dfr(setNames, c("site", "plot", "camera", "date", "time", "ext")) %>%
  tidyr::separate(date, into = c("year", "month", "day"), sep = c(4, 6)) %>%
  tidyr::separate(time, into = c("hour", "minute", "second"), sep = c(2, 4)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-ext)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 9
#>   site  plot  camera year  month day   hour  minute second
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 S123  P2    C10    2012  06    21    21    34     22    
#> 2 S10   P1    C1     2012  06    22    05    01     48    
#> 3 S187  P2    C2     2012  07    02    02    35     01
```

The `ext` column was leftover from the initial string splitting, so you can drop it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `str_sub` or `str_split` other than the fact that they may be efforts to adapt the `sub` and `strsplit` functions to an alternate universe.  I just learned base R and have not really seen the need to learn a new syntax. Here's a base solution:

```
as.POSIXct( sub( "([^_]+[_])(\\d{8})[_](\\d{6})", "\\2 \\4", file.names) , format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
[1] "2012-06-21" "2012-06-22" "2012-07-02"
```

You can real the `sub` pattern as

```
1) beginning with the start of the string  collect all the non-underscore characters into the first capture group
2) Then get the next 8 digits (if they exist) in a second capture group 
3) and everything that follows will be in a third capture group
```

The substitution is to just return the contents of the second capture group. The conversion to Date values is straightforward. I'm assuming that should be clear from the code, but if not then see `?as.Date`.

Here's the rest;

```
as.POSIXct( sub( "([^_]+[_])(\\d{8})[_](\\d{6})(.+$)", "\\2 \\3", file.names) , 
            format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
[1] "2012-06-21 21:34:22 PDT" "2012-06-22 05:01:48 PDT" "2012-07-02 02:35:01 PDT"
```

If you want the break out then convert to `POSIXlt` and extract the resulting list.